# Empty RequestsCookieJar in Python requests

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, httprequest, instagram

I'm working with Python requests module.

```
>>> import requests
>>> s1 = requests.Session()
>>> r1 = s1.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
>>> r1.cookies
<RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='fr', ... ]>
```

i.e. the `RequestsCookieJar` is full, and It is full for every url I try. But for Instagram I get:

```
>>> s2 = requests.Session()
>>> r2 = s2.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
>>> r2.cookies
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
```

i.e. the `RequestsCookieJar` is empty, but it should return something.

Could someone please explain me why this is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: What are the response headers?

Comment: @KlausD. the response headers for `r2` is:  
`{'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Cache-Control': 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT', 'Vary': 'Cookie, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding', 'Content-Language': 'en', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Date': 'Wed, 30 May 2018 11:06:59 GMT', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=86400', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '5528'}`

Answer (score 2):

Its because of instagram. When you open instagram firstly it won't send you cookies, you have to log in, or make a get request again.

Update: As you want to login, and want csrf token, there is the method:

```
import json
import requests
import lxml.html

def get_csrf_token(content):
    xpath_data = lxml.html.fromstring(content).xpath('/html/body/script[1]/text()')[0]
    raw_json = xpath_data[xpath_data.find('{'):-1]
    return json.loads(raw_json)["config"]["csrf_token"]

def get_main_page():
    session = requests.Session()
    content = session.get('https://instagram.com')

    csrf_token = get_csrf_token(content.content)
    header = {'x-csrftoken'      : csrf_token,
              'x-requested-with' : 'XMLHttpRequest',
              'User-Agent'       : "Your user agent there",
              "referer"          : 'https://instagram.com',
              "cookie"           : "ig_cb=1",
              "origin"           : 'https://instagram.com'}

    session.headers.update(header)
```

I assume that you could write the "POST" method to pass through login.

Comment: If I do get request twice I still have empty `RequestsCookieJar`, and in order to log in you need the `csrftoken` which comes with cookies of the the first get request.

Comment: Thats not true! You could fetch the csrftoken. I will update my answer

Comment: Ok, I got it. The problem was that I missed `"cookie": "ig_cb=1"` in my request header. What is it for? With that the GET resquest returns a non-empty `RequestsCookieJar`. So it is unnecessary to scrape the page and look for the `csrf_token`.